# Error '1004' when adding individual cells to a chart range in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add individual cells to a chart so that only cells that meet a certain criteria are added to the chart.

```
ChartXDataString = "="
ChartFuelDriveDataString = "="

For i = 0 To 5 

    If Range("AP" & FirstDataRow + i) <> "0" Then

        If i = 5 Then
            ChartXDataString = ChartXDataString & "'RAW FleetData'!$A$" & (FirstDataRow + i)
            ChartFuelDriveDataString = ChartFuelDriveDataString & "'RAW FleetData'!$AP$" & (FirstDataRow + i)
        Else
            ChartXDataString = ChartXDataString & "'RAW FleetData'!$A$" & (FirstDataRow + i) & ";"
            ChartFuelDriveDataString = ChartFuelDriveDataString & "'RAW FleetData'!$AP$" & (FirstDataRow + i) & ";"
        End If
    End If
Next i

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("gFMP_TotalFuelLiters").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ChartXDataString
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ChartFuelDriveDataString
```

When I run the code Excel throws the following error: `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.`

It does so on the line:   `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ChartXDataString`

Even when I record a macro adding individual cells, the chart works until I run the recorded macro, where it throws the error.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of `ChartXDataString` when the error raises?

Comment: I think the problem is that you can't assign formula to `.values` and `.xvalues` properties of `SeriesCollection object`. Try to use `.Formula` property but change the way you create your `chartXDataString or CharterFuelDriveDataString variables`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the macro recorder recorded in the wrong format.
Instead of, as the recorder made, 
ChartXDataString = "='RAW FleetData'!$A$2;'RAW FleetData'!$A$3;'RAW FleetData'!$A$4", 
the correct format is 
"=('RAW FleetData'!$A$2,'RAW FleetData'!$A$3,'RAW FleetData'!$A$4)" 
with parentheses and comma separator